# Recursive fold only up to &foldlevel?

Tags: vimscript, folding

I often use `zC` to close nested folds under the cursor. However this command is not useful in files with a single, global level-zero fold (e.g. fortran `program...end program` and latex `\begin{document}...\end{document}`). In these files I typically use `setlocal foldlevel=1` and rarely want to fold below that level.

Are there any commands or functions I can use to recursively close folds under the cursor *only up to the current fold level*? Perhaps this needs a custom function?

Answer (score 1):

Alright this wasn't too difficult. Adding this to `vimrc` does the trick:

```
" Nested close function
function! s:close_nested() abort
  let line = line('.')
  while line > 1 && foldlevel(line - 1) > &l:foldlevel
    let line -= 1  " stop when preceding line matches desired level
  endwhile
  exe line . 'foldclose'
endfunction

" Nested close mapping
" Note: When called on line below fold level this will still trigger a close. So
" pressing e.g. 'zCzC' will first fold up to foldlevel then fold additional levels.
noremap zC <Cmd>call s:close_nested()<CR>
```